# Is it possible to remove duplicates from search results?

Tags: support, search

I am using the following query (in the top-right search field): `[worklight] is:question answers:0`.

Some of the results are marked with `[duplicate]`.

Is it possible to exclude these? I could not see a proper option for this in the search help section.

Comment: Bear in mind that duplicates *can* be very useful when searching - more than a few times I've found the post I'm looking for, in spite of forgetting the terminology used in it, by following a chain of duplicates.

Comment: @Shog9, you are right, but for my particular need this is of no consequence. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes,

You can use `duplicate:no`. To exclude *all* closed questions use `closed:no`

See the [search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)